# Querying with Lucene in C#

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm new to Lucene. I have some business objects that are stored in a database. When I retrieve them, I index them with Lucene.NET as shown here:

```
List<MyEntity> myResults = GetResultsFromDb();
using (var indexService = new IndexService(indexWriter))
{
  indexService.IndexEntities(myResults, p =>
  {
    var document = new Document();
    document.Add(new Field("ID", p.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("Name", p.Name, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("Description", p.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    document.Add(new Field("IsActive", p.IsActive.ToString(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    return document;
  });
}
```

I'm now trying to search for business objects with a similar Name. In an attempt to perform that search, I'm using the following:

```
  var indexSearcher = new DirectoryIndexSearcher(new   DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Index")), true);
  using (var searchService = new SearchService(indexSearcher))
  {
    TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Name", GetNameToSearchWith()));                    

    SearchResult<MyEntity> searchResults = searchService.SearchIndex<CourseSearchResult>(termQuery, new MyEntityDefinition());
    foreach (CourseSearchResult searchResult in searchResults.Results)
    {
      filteredResults.Results.Add(searchResult);
      if (filteredResults.Count() >= 25)
        break;
    }
  }
```

When I execute my query, I retrieve results. The problem is, the only value that is populated is the "Name" field. In the case of MyEntity, ID is a Guid, Description is a String, and IsActive is a nullable bool. When I execute my query, the ID is always an empty Guid, the IsActive flag is always null and Description is always an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DirectoryIndexSearcher is not a part of standard Lucene.Net distribution. This is part of SimpleLucene (http://simplelucene.codeplex.com) library. I would try to implement same search query without simplelucene. And if it works properly, then try to debug why simplelucene isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you tell Lucene in the document not to store those data in the document. you should change Field.Store.NO to Field.Store.YES for all the fields you want to retrieve from documents during a search.